# Gmail API send message utf-8 header

Tags: utf-8, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, mime

I've been trying to use Gmail API for python for some code and I ran into some problem. I try so send some mail through this API to myself so I wrote the following minimal code:

```py
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header

mime = MIMEMultipart()
mime['To'] = Header("example@example.com") #Works
#mime['To'] = Header("example@example.com", 'utf-8') #Error: Invalid To header
mime['From'] = "me"
mime['Subject'] = "Hello World"
output =  {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mime.as_string().encode()).decode()}
service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=output).execute()
```

where service is the object created by [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and I based my code on [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending).

As you can see the code runs or fails based on the encoding of the 'To' header. This is weird because changing the encoding of the 'From' Header or of the 'Subject' doesn't have this effect.

(I know that in this case a utf-8 encoded string isn't needed for the 'To' header but in my case it is needed)

Comment: I don't think this is related to Gmail API but to `Header` and `MIMEMultipart`. Is it the same exact header value and charset that works in `From` but not in `To`?

Comment: Headers cannot be encoded in UTF-8 (not directly). There is a different way to encode them.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi But it does work for the "From" and "Subject" header. Replacing `"Hello World"` with `Header("Hello World", 'utf-8')` still works

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I can execute `mime['To'] = Header("example@example.com", 'utf-8')` successfully. Which line are you getting this error?

Comment: The last line, the one trying to send this message through Gmail API